# Consigo acessar o Tomcat por lynx http://localhost:8080, porém, não consigo pelo browser da Maquina local

Tags: apache, aplicação-web, tomcat, centos

Estou com um problema para conseguir fazero tomcat ser acessado por http:// de qualquer lugar.

Para vocês entenderem melhor:

Eu tenho uma VM CENTOS 6.6 e nela eu instalei o TOMCAT 7 e o JAVA 7
Reiniciei o Tomcat e se eu tentar acessar página do tomcat por lynx conforme abaixo funciona normal:

```
  lynx http://localhost:8080
```

Porém, se eu tentar acessar o tomcat do meu computador (pelo Chrome) conforme abaixo, não funciona

```
   http://ipAddress:8080
```

Vocês poderiam me ajudar a entender por que da VM eu consigo acessar o Tomcat por http, porém, de uma maquina local eu nao consigo acessar?
Poderiam me ajudar a reverter essa situação, ou seja oque eu preciso configurar e como configurar para conseguir acessa o http pelo?

Comment: Pode ser o firewall da sua VM

Comment: como eu consigo resolver esse problema?

Comment: André, é muito difícil te ajudar sem saber exatamente o que você já fez e ter mais detalhes sobre seu ambiente: Que tipo de VM é essa (Virtual Box?)? O Guest está com as portas abertas? O adaptador de rede da VM está configurado em nodo bridge ou NAT? As máquinas que estão tentando acessar a VM estão na mesma rede? Você ao menos consegue acessar a porta 8080 do guest a partir da máquina host? Como está configurado o Connector no `server.xml` do Tomcat? E o Apache, como está entrando na jogada?